# Google Currents like Viewpager + adapter (not indicator)

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-gridview

I'm learning how to build an adapter like the one demonstrated in Currents. 
I know the basic classes used to achieve what we see in currents : ViewPager, ViewPagerIndicator, and a custom view showing 6 ImageViews and textviews below it.

[image: Google Currents Screenshot]

My question is, how do we go about building a custom adapter that will automatically fill in 6 items in the first viewpager page, and continue filling it on the next page automatically? I'm guessing it will be something along the idea where the number returned from getCount() will be used to determine how many viewpager "pages" are there, (in this case divide by 6 ).

I have successfully tried building a similar view using GridView + viewpager+indicator, but i'm sure Currents is not using gridview to achieve this. Since this is definitely not extending ListView nor GridView, how can i go about solving this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was pretty convinced you're doing it exactly how google currents did. I'll be standing by if you ever find out(or confirm) your theory. :)

Comment: Hey! Stark did you found any solution for your problem ?